# How do i precisely track the script execution time. This includes HTTP requests / CURL requests in the script

Tags: php, time

I would like to know how to precisely track the script execution time and tapout before it reaches the timeout. For some reason there is a weird issue when multiple processes are running at the same time **(different scripts, same file, with two browser tabs)**. The script execution time for the second script is twice as long compared to the script which was executed first. It would sound perfectly reasonable  when the tracker would also account for that but for some reason the second script's timer seems to provide false estimates so i'm unable to tapout before it reaches timeout.

Here's the script which i'm running.

```
public function insertProducts(DB $db, $type){

    //Import variations, first parent then children
    $startedInsert = microtime(true);

    list($variantProducts,$simpleProducts) = $this->prepareProducts($db,'insert',$type);

    $importedSkus = [];
    $importedIds = [];
    $tracker = [];
    
    switch($type){

        case 'variable':

            if(!empty($variantProducts)){

                
                foreach($variantProducts as $variationIdentifier => $variants){
                    
                    //if((microtime(true) - $startedInsert) / 60 >= 3) break;

                    $startVariant = microtime(true);

                    $existingVariantParent = $this->getVariantParent($db,$variationIdentifier);
                    
                    $exists = false;
                    if($existingVariantParent){
                        $variantParent = $this->request('GET', 'v3/products/P'.$existingVariantParent.'T');
                        $parentId = $existingVariantParent;
                        $exists = isset($variantParent['code']) ? false : true;
                    }
    
                    
                    // If the parent does not exist, insert a new one
                    if(!$exists){
                        $parent = $variants[0];
                        $parent['sku'] = 'P'.$variants[0]['sku'].'T';
                        $existingImages = $this->getMedias(array_column($parent['images'], 'name'));
    
                        if(!empty($existingImages)){
    
                            $parent['images'] = array_map(function($item) use($existingImages){
                                $item = current(array_filter($existingImages, function($exisitngImage) use($item){ return $item['name'] === $exisitngImage['name'] ? true : false; })) ?: $item;
                                return $item;
                            }, $parent['images']);
    
                        }
    
                        $variantParent = $this->request('POST', 'v3/products', $parent);  

                        $tracker['variant']['parent'][] = $variantParent;
                        
                        if(isset($variantParent['code'])){
                            if(isset($variantParent['data']['resource_id'])){
                                $parentId = $variantParent['data']['resource_id'];
                            }
                        }else{
                            $parentId = $variantParent['id'];
                        }
                        
                        $this->setVariantParent($db,$variationIdentifier,$parentId,$variants[0]['sku']);
                        $importedSkus[] = $variants[0]['sku'];
                    }

                    if(!isset($parentId)) continue;
                    
                    $importedIds[] = $parentId;
                    
                    $tracker['variant']['parent']['stopwatch'][] = (microtime(true) - $startVariant) / 60; 

                    $startVariants = microtime(true);
                    if(!empty($variants)){
                        $images = [];
                        $variantImageNames = array_unique(array_reduce($variants, function($carry, $item){
                            $carry = array_merge($carry, array_column($item['images'], 'name'));
                            return $carry;
                        }, []));       
                        $existingImages = $this->getMedias($variantImageNames);
                        $variants = array_map(function($item) use($variantParent,&$images,$existingImages){
                            $attributes = [];
                            
                            if(isset($variantParent['attributes'])){
                                foreach($item['attributes'] as $attr){
        
                                    $attributes[] = array_reduce($variantParent['attributes'], function($carry, $item) use($attr){
                                        if($attr['name'] === $item['name'] && $item['variation']){
                                            $carry = [
                                                'id' => $attr['id'],
                                                'option' => $attr['options'][0]
                                            ];
                                        }
        
                                        return $carry;
                                    });
        
                                }
                                $item['attributes'] = array_filter($attributes);
                            }
                            if(!empty($item['images'])){
                                if(!in_array($item['images'][0]['name'], $images)){
                                    
                                    $imageName = $item['images'][0]['name'];
                                    $item['image'] = current(array_filter($existingImages, function($exisitngImage) use ($imageName){  return $exisitngImage['name'] == $imageName ? true : false; })) ?: $item['images'][0];
                                    $images[] = $imageName;
        
                                }
                            }
                            
                            return $item;
                        },$variants);
    
                        //$variants
                        $variants = $this->request('POST', 'v3/products/'.$parentId.'/variations/batch', ['create' => $variants]);
                        $tracker['variant']['variants'][] = $variants;

                        $skus = array_reduce($variants['create'], function($carry, $item){
                            if(!isset($item['error'])){
                                $carry[] = $item['sku'];
                            }
                            return $carry;
                        });
                        if(!empty($skus)){
                            $importedSkus = array_merge($importedSkus,$skus);
                        }
                        
                    }
                    $tracker['variant']['variant']['stopwatch'][] = (microtime(true) - $startVariants) / 60; 
    
                }
                $tracker['endedVariant'] = (microtime(true) - $startedInsert) / 60;
            }
    
            
        break;

        case 'simple':
            if(!empty($simpleProducts)){

                $simpleImageNames = array_unique(array_reduce($simpleProducts, function($carry, $item){
                    $carry = array_merge($carry, array_column($item['images'], 'name'));
                    return $carry;
                }, []));       
                $existingImages = $this->getMedias($simpleImageNames);
                $images = [];

                $simpleProducts = array_map(function($item) use($existingImages,&$images){
                    
                    foreach($item['images'] as $imageKey => $image){
                        $imageName = $image['name'];
                        $item['images'][$imageKey] = current(array_filter($existingImages, function($exisitngImage) use ($imageName){  return $exisitngImage['name'] == $imageName ? true : false; })) ?: $item['images'][$imageKey];
                        if(!isset($item['images'][$imageKey]['id'])){
                            if(!in_array($item['images'][$imageKey]['name'],$images)){
                                $images[] = $item['images'][$imageKey]['name'];
                            }else{

                                // Prevent duplicate image uploads on simple products
                                unset($item['images'][$imageKey]);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    return $item;
                },$simpleProducts);

                $simpleProduct = $this->request('POST', 'v3/products/batch', ['create' => $simpleProducts]);
                $importedSImples = array_reduce($simpleProduct['create'], function($carry, $item){
                    if(!isset($item['error'])){
                        $carry['skus'][] = $item['sku'];
                        $carry['ids'][] = $item['id'];
                    }else if(isset($item['error']['data']['resource_id'])){
                        $carry['ids'][] = $item['error']['data']['resource_id'];
                    }
                    return $carry;
                },['skus' => [],'ids' => []]);
                $importedSkus = array_merge($importedSkus,$importedSImples['skus']);
                $importedIds = array_merge($importedSkus,$importedSImples['ids']);

                $tracker['endedSimple'] = (microtime(true) - $startedInsert) / 60;
            }

            
            $tracker['simple'] = $simpleProduct;
        break;
    }
    
    // $startDelete = microtime(true);
    // $this->request('POST', 'v3/products/batch', ['delete' => $importedIds]);
    // $endDelete = microtime(true);
    // $tracker['deleted'] = ($endDelete - $startDelete) / 60;
    
    
    if(!empty($importedIds)){
        $existingProducts = $this->request('GET','v3/products', ['include' => $importedIds]);
        $importedSkus = array_merge($importedSkus, array_column($existingProducts,'sku'));
    }

    if(!empty($importedSkus)){
        $this->updateDB($db, 'insert',array_filter($importedSkus));
    }

    $tracker['imported_ids'] = $importedIds;
    $tracker['imported_skus'] = $importedSkus;   

    var_dump($tracker);
}
```

At first i initate the tracker and prepare products for insertion

```
//Import variations, first parent then children
$startedInsert = microtime(true);

list($variantProducts,$simpleProducts) = $this->prepareProducts($db,'insert',$type);
```

Then incase the type is set variable i execute the variable product insertion and in a perfect scenario this would break out of the foreach loop, finish rest of the processes and end the script once it has reached to 3 minute line. Right now, this seems to malfunction.

```
//if((microtime(true) - $startedInsert) / 60 >= 3) break; // This would break out in 3 minutes
enter code here
```

At the end of this script i get how long did it take to execute the whole process for variable products insertion

```
$tracker['endedVariant'] = (microtime(true) - $startedInsert) / 60;
```

The same tracking logic applies to simple type as well, except there is no breaking out.

Now when i would init both of these scripts on different browser tabs, the simple product would show **1.5min** and the variable approx **2.** So a great idea would be to increase the payload right? The timeout happens at 300s so i would prefer if the scripts end a little before that and wait for the next execution.

Whenever i would increase the payload sent to the api, by a little, it timouts and rest of the script is ignored. The part which is suppose to breakout for variable products is ignored which makes me believe that the tracking is wrong.

I tested by starting both of these scripts on different browser tabs and also starting a stopwatch on my phone. The numbers don't match. For variable products the execution time is twice as long on the phone compared to the stopwatch that tracks the execution time. When i execute these scripts one at a time, the stopwatch is correct. What is happening here?

Btw, i am aware of increasing the timeout, i'm on a shared hosting so i'm limited to 300s. Also starting the script on shell, still timeouts on 300s. What i want to accomplish is to squeeze out as much processing as possible in a 5min/300sec timeframe. The scripts are later executed using cron jobs but for now i'm just testing these on a browser.

Comment: php is probably blocking execution of the next script, causing a delay in it's actual start.

Comment: Thats what i was thinking, any ideas how it could be solved or managed differently?

Comment: well honestly you never described what you are trying to accomplish, and I am not going to try to parse that wall of code. what are you doing? uploading a file? filling out a giant form? getting data from a 3rd party API? then inserting a bunch of records into the database? describe it all and i'll see if anything comes to mind.

Comment: Basically i'm sending data from my database to an API. The only issue i have is senging data efficiently by sending as much data as possible in a 5 minute timeframe.

Comment: if this requires no user input, have you considered running the script via command line, or as a cron job? this would allow the script to keep running as long as you need it to.

Comment: @dqhendricks Since i'm on a shared hosting, fastcgi timeout still occurs even with the command line approach. It is already working as a cron job but it is not as efficient as possible since i can't manage how much data gets processed in that 5 minute range. The data is constantly changing so setting a fixed number won't work also because in one case 20 items takes 1 min, in other it could take 2-3 etc. Thats why i need a breakout approach to breakout from the loop before it reaches the timeout.